# Restrictions on the parameterization of a definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

This is an arbitrary thought which came to my mind today. My background in mathematics is restricted by my being an engineer. Suppose I have a definite integral such that
$$I=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\mathrm{d}x$$
Now, were $f(x)$ too complicated to be handled singly, it would make sense to parameterize $x$ to $x=g(\lambda)$ such that
$$I=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\mathrm{d}x=\int_{g^{-1}(a)}^{g^{-1}(b)}f(g(\lambda))\left(\frac{dg(\lambda)}{d\lambda}\right)\mathrm{d}\lambda$$

Now, suppose I had a function $g(\lambda)$ such that it is multivalued to the extent of $g(\lambda_0)=a=b$, in that case I would have $I=0$, which, I guess, would not be otherwise necessarily true. Am I missing the point somehow here or is there some complex mathematical restriction on what kind of functions, I could parameterize using a special class of functions or anything on that line. Any and every help is appreciated :)

Comment: If $g(\lambda_0)$ has two distinct values then $g$ isn't a function, so I'd say it's not even a worthy candidate for the parameterization $x = g(\lambda)$.

Comment: @tilper: but $x=\sin^{-1}\lambda$ is used a lot from my experience.

Comment: When we use arcsine we [restrict its range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) to avoid any issues like that.  For example, although it is true that infinitely many values of $x$ satisfy $\sin x = 1$, the value of $\arcsin 1$ is $\pi/2$ and nothing else (unless we restrict the range of arcsine to be some other interval, but whatever interval we choose must be chosen so as to avoid the possibility of $\arcsin y$ having more than one value, since otherwise arcsine is then not a function).